# D3.js tree custom node overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I searched the forum for similar problem but I did not find anything.

I am using [this d3-based org chart](http://blog.zubasoft.at/Examples/D3.js/OrgChart/index.htm) as a starting point.

[image]

Above is the bottom part of my tree. On the **leaf nodes** (yellow) I have to resize them to accommodate more elements which I don't know how many in advance.
The result is one node overlaps other nodes.

Hope you guys can help me out here:

**1/** How do I resize the nodes without disrepect the spacing between them?

**2/** Even if I can manage to make nodes on yellow branch *not overlapped*, when I expand nodes on *green branch*, they still overlap nodes on the yellow side?

**3/** or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to do something similar, **[Tree layout separation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Tree-Layout.md#separation)** is the way to go.

```
function separation (a, b) {
   return a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2; 
}
```

It's confusing reading the doc (**what does number 1,2 mean?**), but after looking through some articles, here goes:

> The distance between nodes will be the result of **that number** times **node's width**

So, what you'd want to do is set default node's size to be 
**[1, YOUR_DEFAULT_HEIGHT]**

Then instead of return **1 or 2**, you'd return the **node's width**. That's why you set initial node's width to be **1.**

That's it. Hope that helps :)